# How to convert string to integer in Javascript(Rhino) Programming Language?

Tags: string, int, rhino

I have one variable which contains integer values in string format as given below:

```
strValue = "123"
```

I want to convert this string value to integer type so it will be helpful for mathematical operation.

How can I do that in Javascript(Rhino) Language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `parseInt` function that recieves a string and returns int.

Example:

```
var string = "123"
var number = parseInt(string)

print(number * 2)
```